# Why is std::bad_cast thrown by boost::locale?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, locale

I try to understand how to use boost::locale to compare strings ignoring case and variants. I directly tried a code from Boost documentation :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/collation.html

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale vLocale = gen("");


std::wstring a=L"Façade", b=L"facade";

// Following will throw bad_cast
bool eq = std::use_facet<boost::locale::collator<wchar_t>>(vLocale).compare(
    boost::locale::collator_base::secondary,
    a,
    b
) == 0;

if(eq) std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
```

This code will throw a std::bad_cast exception when running.
I tried a lot of parameters in the constructor of boost::locale::generator. Does anyone know about the problem I encounter ?

I am using C++11 with g++4.6 and Boost 1.51.0

Comment: Just as a hint, the `bad_cast` _exception_ is signaling that the given `locale` does not have the requested `facet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are using an incorrect locale object. First, you should use global locale and then (if you want to use `std::cout`) imbue the locale to the stream. Something like this:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen("");
std::locale::global(loc);
```

But, in your example, if you are not using `std::cout`, just set global locale so you have the required facets ready.

Comment: There isn't any need for `std::use_facet<F>(l)` to have a specific global `std::locale` to be set! It rather seems the locale object doesn't contain the required facet.

Comment: Ues it seems my locale does not have my collator facet. But I created it with a generator and I expected It to contain one.. :(

Comment: Also, text segmentation requires ICU, make sure you compile boost with ICU support, this can be easily done via homebrew like this: `brew install boost --with-icu4c --cxx11` and then compiling with `-I/usr/local/include` and linking with `-L/usr/local/lib -lboost_locale-mt`